# Any disadvantage to creating a class which uses methods which return a Task<T> but are synchronous methods over methods returning T

Tags: c#, oop

Let's say we have this class - **MyClass**

**MyClass** has methods that convert different types of lists to XDocuments

As an example we'll just look at one method, Convert

I could write this method as:

```
public XDocument Convert<T>(IList<T> myList)
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument("root");
    //Do some synchronous work       
    return doc;
}
```

Or I could write it like the following:

```
public Task<XDocument> Convert<T>(IList<T> myList)
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument("root");
    //Do some synchronous work       
    return Task.FromResult(doc);
}
```

Now imagine we want to offload this to a Task in another part of our program, while some other tasks are doing some work and then await them all to complete before doing some other work inside the async method.

I know with the first version of the method, I could do:

```
some async method...

Task t = Task.Run(() => myClass.Convert<T>(IList<T>);
Task t2...
Task t3...
await Task.WhenAll(t, t2, t3);
```

But with the second form of the method, it seems more simplistic to be able to do:

```
some async method...

Task t = myClass.Convert<T>(IList<T>);
Task t2...
Task t3...
await Task.WhenAll(t, t2, t3);
```

My question is:

Is there any downside to designing the method like the second example? To return a Task for ease of use in running as Task elsewhere in the code base, even though it is synchronous. Or is this more about intent?

**I know this may be considered an opinionated question, so I will probably remove it from SO after I have given it enough time to gain some responses. Otherwise, if considered a specific enough and good question, I will leave it.**

Comment: If you aren't awaiting, there's no need to use Tasks, unless you have multiple implementations and need to match an interface. `Task.Run` can swallow errors, so make sure you handle them in the code it calls. Unless you're loading a document from disk, I don't see the reason to use either case with your current examples. I'd leave it as a non-task until you need async functionality. Async/await does add some extra overhead. This may be a better question for the code review site, though.

Comment: @ps2goat Let's say we are in another part of the code base, inside an async method, we want to offload the work of converting the list to a XDocument onto a task as well as maybe doing work on some other tasks and then awaiting all of these tasks to complete before doing some more things in the method. Does that make things more clear as to why the Convert method would be designed to return Task<T>?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok. I get that there may be overhead from your explanation and I didn't have the full example shown in my original question, I updated to hopefully display more of what I'm looking at this design choice for: If it's not clear in my updated question, it's on the assumption we are doing the Convert on a Task while other operations are being done on some other Tasks and then awaiting all the tasks to complete before doing some more work inside the async method, does that make sense?

Comment: For people voting to close: `I  know this may be considered an opinionated question, so I will probably remove it from SO after I have given it enough time to gain some responses. Otherwise, if considered a specific enough and good question, I will leave it."

Comment: So you think that changing the signature of a method to return a `Task<T>` instead of `T` is the same as `Task.Run`ing the method? If you do, then you are wrong. It is perfectly possible to implement a badly-behaving method that has an asynchronous contract and a synchronous implementation. A method that instead of handing to the caller an incomplete `Task`, it forces the caller to do all the work synchronously, and finally it hands back a complete `Task`. That's what the second `Convert` is essentially doing.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias In the context of Task t = second version of method; Task t2 = someother method; Task t3 = someotherothermethod; await. Task.WhenAll(t, t2, t3); How is this bad? How does it force the caller to do anything as it's being delegated to a Task object? And no I don't think the two are equivalent. I understand that Task.Run moves the work to a threadpool thread. But to be able to await the synchronous work of the first version of the method, Task.Run is the only way to do so as it doesn't return a Task or Task<T>

Comment: All three tasks `t`, `t1` and `t2` will be created in a completed state. Then the combined task `Task.WhenAll(t, t2, t3)` will be instantly completed on creation as well. In short nothing will happen **a**synchronously. The current thread will simply execute all three `Convert` invocations the one after the other, in exactly the same way as if the `Convert` was returning an `XDocument` instead of `Task<XDocument>`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you. That is the part I was cloudy on and was looking to understand. I'd like to delete this post but it won't let me since someone provided an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any downside to designing the method like the second example?

Yes. The method is synchronous, but it has an asynchronous signature. This is a poor design choice.

This can easily cause accidental misuse. Say, for example...

> it seems more simplistic to be able to do

That code won't work the way you think it will. The tasks will not run in parallel. Because the code is synchronous; it just has an asynchronous *signature*.

And if you think of using `Task.Run` as the implementation of a fake-asynchronous method, [that's also considered a bad practice](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/).

Comment: Thank you. This and what was given in the last of the comments was what I was looking for all along. I just needed someone to show me what has been pointed out, "my code doesn't do what I thought it did". Thanks again!

Comment: I read that article you posted for me, thanks for that. It sounds as if I wanted to do some work in parallel and the only option of my class method is synchronous, that may be a time to use `Task.Run()` or am I completely reading that wrong?

Comment: @RyanWilson: I recommend [using `Task.Run` when *calling* a method, not as the implementation of the method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Comment: Thank you. I read your post and I think that clarified things further for me, I appreciate you taking the time to explain this to me.

Comment: I feel kind of foolish after getting your feedback and looking at what I had been doing in my code, it seems so obvious that I was just setting a Task variable to a completed Task and that the method was just being called and completed before the next declaration of a Task. I don't know why I spaced out on this one, but thanks again for your time and explanations.

Comment: @RyanWilson: It's not an uncommon mistake.

Comment: I have a hypthetical, let's say I have a method and all work in the method is synchronous except for a call to a logger for logging an exception message, ie. the only time it uses an async operation is when an exception occurs inside the method, is it better to rewrite the method as synchronous and log exception synchronously, or leave it as an async method since the logging in the catch block is asynchronous?

Comment: @RyanWilson: All logging implementations I'm aware of are synchronous, primarily for this reason.

Comment: Thank you. I kind of rolled my own logging, which utilizes a WCF service and a database table, so the endpoint exposes an `async` version, probably bad design on my part once again. (Sigh)

Answer (score 2):

Your two examples do not do the same thing. In the first example, where you use `Task.Run`, you are spinning work off to the thread pool to execute in parallel. Asynchronous tasks do not use the thread pool; they use cooperative multitasking to complete asynchronous operations in parallel.

Comment: I understand that `Task.Run` moves the work onto a threadpool thread, my question is more about whether designing the class method to return a `Task<T>` for use in an async method while other tasks are doing other independent work and then awaiting them all whether it's bad to design those methods in the class that way? I do appreciate you taking time to contribute though.