# Make methods run asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task

Can someone please look at this code and tell me what I am doing wrong. It seems to me that this 3 methods should run in the same same, but they run each after another. Please take look at time writen on console. In my opinion all Console.WriteLine should show ~60ms.
Code sample below:

```
private async void GetOneCombination(string firstMarket, string secondMarket, string thirdMarket, decimal amountOfFirstCurrency)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        Task<GetMarketResponse> result = _accessMethods.GetOrderbook(firstMarket);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // ~60ms
        Task<GetMarketResponse> result1 = _accessMethods.GetOrderbook(secondMarket);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // ~130 ms
        Task<GetMarketResponse> result2 = _accessMethods.GetOrderbook(thirdMarket);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); // ~200 ms
        var getMarketResponses = await Task.WhenAll(result, result1, result2);

    }
```

Edit:
To be hosnest I thought that it don`t matter whats inside this methods, i thought that no matter what is done inside it will be done 3 times at the same time

```
  public async Task<GetMarketResponse> GetOrderbook(string market = "USD")
    {
        var address = AddressBook._orderbook + market;
        var response = MethodExecutionTimeMeasurer.Invoke(() => 
            _client.ExecuteGetAsyncPublic<GetMarketResponse>(address), out timespan);
        _logger.LogInformation(string.Format("OrderBook requested for [{0}], response message: {1}. Time[ms]:{2}", 
            address, 
            response.Status,
            timespan));
        return response; 
    }
```

and ExecuteGetAsyncPublic:

```
   public async Task<T> ExecuteGetAsyncPublic<T>(string method)
        where T : IBasicResponse
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(method).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        return responseData;
    }
```

MethodExecutionTimeMeasurer

```
public static class MethodExecutionTimeMeasurer
{
    public static T Invoke<T>(Func<Task<T>> action, out TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var res = action.Invoke();
        res.Wait();
        timer.Stop();
        timeSpan = timer.Elapsed;
        return res.Result;
    }

    public static void Invoke(Action action, out TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        action.Invoke();
        timer.Stop();
        timeSpan = timer.Elapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what does it show if you `var resultX = await _accessMethods.GetOrderbook()` three times? Show the code of GetOrderbook too

Comment: As a side note, [avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). Use `async Task` instead. Regarding your main question, could you edit it and include the `GetOrderbook` method?

Comment: Beside the note from @Theodor Zoulias (better return a Task instead of void here) which i agree, in this case i guess the implementation from the methods are the problem (but thats hard to see without seeing the implementation).   What you can easy try to figure that out,   wrap each call in `Task.Run(() => _access.methods.Getorderbook(...));`   (only to test this)

Comment: Thaks for response, I edited post.

Comment: Yes, I was adding it as you wrote this. I have this res.Stop() which seems to be the problem. But can you explain me why? Im new to async methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. The `GetOrderbook` method has an asynchronous signature, but its implementation is synchronous. You are probably getting a warning for the `async` method lacking an [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) operator.
2. The `MethodExecutionTimeMeasurer.Invoke` has a parameter `Func<Task<T>> action` (an asynchronous delegate), but the created `Task` is waited synchronously with the [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait) method. So during the task's execution, the current thread is blocked.

Each of the three `_accessMethods.GetOrderbook` invocations returns a completed task, then the combined task `Task.WhenAll(result, result1, result2)` is also completed upon creation, and in short from the current thread's perspective nothing is running **a**synchronously. This case is very similar with a question that was asked yesterday, [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617912/any-disadvantage-to-creating-a-class-which-uses-methods-which-return-a-taskt-b).

Answer (score -1):

Calling an async Task method does not immediately start on a new thread. It will run on the thread that it was called on until it encounters an await.

```
so for example
var task = DoSomething();

public async Task DoSomething()
{
    // MAIN THREAD

    await Task.Delay(1);

    // WORKER THREAD

}
```

If you do it like this it will probably work

```
 public async Task<GetMarketResponse> GetOrderbook(string market = "USD")
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        var address = AddressBook._orderbook + market;
        var response = MethodExecutionTimeMeasurer.Invoke(() => 
            _client.ExecuteGetAsyncPublic<GetMarketResponse>(address), out timespan);
        _logger.LogInformation(string.Format("OrderBook requested for [{0}], response message: {1}. Time[ms]:{2}", 
            address, 
            response.Status,
            timespan));
        return response; 
    }
```

Another approach you can take is

```
Parallel.Invoke(
() => _accessMethods.GetOrderbook(firstMarket).Wait(),
() => _accessMethods.GetOrderbook(secondMarket).Wait(),
() => _accessMethods.GetOrderbook(thirdMarket).Wait(),
);
```